# How to add superscripts to text for buttons in windows forms?

Tags: button, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to create a virtual keyboard like the one we have in windows 10. I am using buttons to represent all the characters on our keyboard. But how do I put text on keys where there are multiple characters like for example on `?` key, we also have a `/`, so how do I do it?

basically this is what I want to do (from windows 10 virtual keyboard)

[image]

but I can only do this as of now:

[image]

So how can I add a superscript kind of thing to make my buttons look more professional?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new Button class that extends the System.Windows.Forms.Button.

```
public class SuperscriptButton : Button
{
    [Browsable(true)]
    public event EventHandler SuperscriptChanged;

    [Browsable(true)]
    public string Superscript
    {
        get
        {
            return _superScript;
        }
        set
        {
            _superScript = value;
            OnSuperscriptChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private string _superScript;

    public SuperscriptButton()
    {
        TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.BottomRight;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
       base.OnPaint(pevent);
       System.Drawing.Graphics g = pevent.Graphics;

       g.DrawString(Superscript, Font, new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(ForeColor), 5, 5);
    }

    private void OnSuperscriptChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if(SuperscriptChanged != null)
            SuperscriptChanged(this, e);
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

Now you can use this button in the designer and change the Superscript property in order to change the displayed character.